# Goofy Toggle Issue with JQuery

Tags: jquery, css, sass

I am attempting to create a grid of 9 tiles - they will serve as home page navigation. The desired effect here is to have each tile be a link (obviously) that has a semi-transparent background and completely opaque text (obviously) fade over the tile on `mouseenter` - and fade out on `mouseleave`.

I have created the desired effect (minus the fade) in CSS (SCSS - actually). I would like to leave this hard coded into CSS if possible - as a fallback if the user has Javascript turned off. But I think this is what is causing my issue.

mouseenter works fine - mouseleave fades out the text, and fades it right back in. How can I prevent this? Code below:

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Lauren Barge Photography</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="common/css/main.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.home_tile_text').hide().removeClass('text').addClass('text-js');
    //$('.home_tile_overlay').hide().removeClass('text').addClass('text-js');

    $('.home_tile').mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).find('.text-js').fadeToggle();
    });
    $('.home_tile').mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).find('.text-js').fadeToggle();
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <h1 class="main_logo">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="common/img/header_logo_sm.jpg" alt="Lauren barge Photography" />
                </a>
            </h1>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
        <h2>Welcome.</h2>
            <div id="home_grid">
                <a href="#" class="home_tile_link">
                    <div class="home_tile" id="home_tile_1">
                        <div class="home_tile_overlay">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="home_tile_text" id="tile_text_1">Tile Number 1</div>
                        <img src="common/img/home_tiles/1.jpg" alt="" class="home_tile_img">
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="home_tile_link">
                    <div class="home_tile" id="home_tile_2">
                        <div class="home_tile_overlay">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="home_tile_text" id="tile_text_2">Tile Number 2</div>
                        <img src="common/img/home_tiles/1.jpg" alt="" class="home_tile_img">
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="home_tile_link">
                    <div class="home_tile" id="home_tile_3">
                        <div class="home_tile_overlay">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="home_tile_text" id="tile_text_3">Tile Number 3</div>
                        <img src="common/img/home_tiles/1.jpg" alt="" class="home_tile_img">
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="home_tile_link">
                    <div class="home_tile" id="home_tile_4">
                        <div class="home_tile_overlay">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="home_tile_text" id="tile_text_4">Tile Number 4</div>
                        <img src="common/img/home_tiles/1.jpg" alt="" class="home_tile_img">
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="home_tile_link">
                    <div class="home_tile" id="home_tile_5">
                        <div class="home_tile_overlay">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="home_tile_text" id="tile_text_5">Tile Number 5</div>
                        <img src="common/img/home_tiles/1.jpg" alt="" class="home_tile_img">
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="home_tile_link">
                    <div class="home_tile" id="home_tile_6">
                        <div class="home_tile_overlay">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="home_tile_text" id="tile_text_6">Tile Number 6</div>
                        <img src="common/img/home_tiles/1.jpg" alt="" class="home_tile_img">
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="home_tile_link">
                    <div class="home_tile" id="home_tile_7">
                        <div class="home_tile_overlay">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="home_tile_text" id="tile_text_7">Tile Number 7</div>
                        <img src="common/img/home_tiles/1.jpg" alt="" class="home_tile_img">
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="home_tile_link">
                    <div class="home_tile" id="home_tile_8">
                        <div class="home_tile_overlay">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="home_tile_text" id="tile_text_8">Tile Number 8</div>
                        <img src="common/img/home_tiles/1.jpg" alt="" class="home_tile_img">
                    </div>
                </a>
                    <div class="home_tile" id="home_tile_9">
                        <img src="common/img/home_tiles/1.jpg" alt="" class="home_tile_img">
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**SCSS**

```
/* SCSS Document */

* { 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

#wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#header {
    padding: 10px 0;
}

#content {
    padding: 0 20px;
}

#home_grid {
    width: 570px;
    margin: 0 auto;

    .home_tile {
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin: 14px;
        float: left;
        position: relative;

        .home_tile_text {
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 40%;
            font-size: 20px;
            color: white;
        }

        .home_tile_overlay {
            width: 150px;
            height: 150px;
            position: absolute;
            display: none;
            background: rgb(250, 96, 28); /* The Fallback */
            background: rgba(250, 96, 28, 0.5); 
        }

        &:hover {
            .home_tile_text {
                display: block;
            }

            .home_tile_overlay {
                display: block;
            }
        }
    }
}

h1.main_logo {
    width: 400px;
    height: 69px;

    a {
        border: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post a functional example that illustrates your problem on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.home_tile_text').hide().removeClass('text').addClass('text-js');
    //$('.home_tile_overlay').hide().removeClass('text').addClass('text-js');

    $('.home_tile').mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).find('.text-js').finish().hide().fadeIn();
    });
    $('.home_tile').mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).find('.text-js').finish().show().fadeOut();
    });
});
```

This first makes sure that any outstanding animations are finished immediately, then, perform the action that we want. Instead of leaving it to chance that fadeToggle will do the right thing, we make sure that we only fade in on "mouseenter" and only fade out on "mouseleave"

Comment: Works like a champ. You are a genius.

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

```
$('.home_tile').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('.text-js').fadeToggle();
},
function(){
    $(this).find('.text-js').fadeToggle();
});
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/P4Zmn/

Demo looks a bit dodgy since it's missing images, but you can see the functionality.

Comment: Up-vote for creating the fiddle - and because it works on the fiddle - but ultimately still did not work on my computer. Weird. Thanks fo rthe help though!